# How call LaunchScreen in applicationWillEnterForeground(_:)

Tags: swift

When the application comes out of the background, it is necessary that the LaunchScreen is loaded after returning to the application.

Is it possible to somehow open the Launch screen through `applicationWillEnterForeground(_:)` ?

I tried to do through `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` - in iOS 13 Deprecated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you can display the launch screen like this:

```
func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "LaunchScreen", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController()!
    if let navigationController = self.window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController
    {
        navigationController.pushViewController(controller, animated: false)
    }
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    if let navigationController = self.window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController
    {
        navigationController.popViewController(animated: false)
    }
}
```

Have to be a **NavigationController** in **Main.storyboard**